# How do I add CRRedist2008_x86.msi to Visual Studio Deployment Project?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, deployment, installation

I need to add CRRedist2008_x86.msi to my deployment project as it is a requirement for my app.  However, I want it to run automatically.  I don't want it to be just added as a file and then the  user has to click on it for it to run after my app installs.  Can someone guide my on how to do this?  It seems like it should be very easy but for some reason I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set it up as a "merge module" in your deployment project. Instead of the .msi, find the.msm file that should be available on the CR website. Then in your deployement project, right click the Project and select Add->Merge Module. Browse for the file and you are set.

When the installer runs, it will automatically unpack the crystal reports related items and install them for you. You may also need a key file, depending on the licensing of the application involved.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason, I got stuck on the new naming.  I was able to select Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 from the list or pre-reqs